# Folder structure while hosting a php app

Tags: php

I have a simple php application and I need to host it.  I have created a free account in 000webhost.com . They have provided me ftp credentials. In my local machine, the directory structure for the project is as follows:

C/wamp/www/myproject

Also I have placed the framework yii from http://www.yiiframework.com/ in the same path above.

When I log in to ftp for the free server account, I can only see the public_html folder. I do not know where I should place myproject and yii folders to host the project successfully.

I have already created database in this free server space using phpmyadmin.

Comment: is php allowed on your server ? usually you should just put files into folder and your main file must be some like index.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the contents of the local folder `/myproject` in the remote `/public_html`

Comment: and where should I place the contents of yii folder?

Comment: You can put it in the same folder. There are advanced options to put it in a folder outside the public_html folder, so it can be used by multiple yii apps, but it will work fine if you put it in the same folder. Based on the fact that you have a free account, my assumption is that you probably can't put it anywhere else...

Comment: I copied the contents of yii in the same folder as that of my project's contents (public_html) . I get the issue as you can see from this url -- http://androidprofessor.net63.net/  .

Comment: Try replacing the first two lines with this code:
`// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';`

Answer (score 1):

just try to upload your files into this folder.

if you upload the whole folder myproject, you have to call it with

```
http://mydomaingivenbymyprovider.com/myproject
```